# Check whether removeable disk is ready in C using biosdisk function

Tags: c, assembly, dos, x86-16, bios

Hello there I'm trying to read data from removeable disk using biosdisk function in C

Where first I have check whether the first removeable disk is ready or not.

To accomplish that the cmd is 16 in biosdisk function.
The complete list of cmd can be seen here
https://it-volume.blogspot.com/2015/02/learning-c-functions-biosdisk-dos-only.html

My code:

```
#include<bios.h>
#include<dos.h>
#include<stdio.h>

FILE *fp;
unsigned char buf[512];
unsigned char st[60];
void main(void)
{
    int i;
    i = biosdisk(16, 0x00, 0, 1, 1, 1, buf);
    if(i == 0xAA)
    {
        printf("The First Removeable drive is not ready");
    }
    else
    {
        printf("\nThe First Removeable drive is ready");
    }
```

Even when there is not removeable disk attached it does not return 0xAA
Instead it returns 0xFF which means "Sense operation failed."
And I have no Idea what "Sense operation failed." means.

How can I get 0xAA in return when the removeable disk is not ready?

Comment: Your link says "0xAA Drive not ready (hard disk only)." That's not a removeable drive. It also says command 16 is allowed only for the XT, AT, PS/2, and compatibles, perhps your isn't. Why don't you just do a read operation?

Comment: ...so what does it return when the drive *is* ready?

Comment: I understand a little. But this is a requirement to check if the disk is ready or not before attempting to read from it.
How am I going to check if Removeable disk is ready or not. Which cmd should I use and what response to expect as a return for such cmd

Comment: You say "when the drive is *not* ready I want it to return 0xAA but it returns 0xFF". What does it return when the drive *is* ready? The program doesn't tell you that vital information, and it should.

Comment: That function is for fixed drives. It isn't documented in your list, but [here](https://sites.google.com/site/pcdosretro/biosfuncs) is described function 016h (22) Get disk change status (floppy disks only) Entry: DL=drive code, Exit: AH=changeline status. 00=changeline not active, 01=invalid diskette parameter, 06=changeline active, 80=drive not ready. If that `biosdisk` function is Borland Turbo C IIR there is another function which can make interrupt calls more directly, and extract the register return values.

Comment: @WeatherVane [Ralph Brown's interrupt list](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0640.htm) says that function 016h should only be called if the drive supports disk change detection. [Function 015h](http://www.ctyme.com/intr/rb-0639.htm) shall be called to check if function 016h is supported. @ student: If the drive does not support disk change detection, the only possibility to check if a disk is in the drive is trying to read from the disk...

Comment: Thanks @MartinRosenau I believe I should just make the code and send it whether its working on my end or not. Because Processors we have now do not work the way 8086 used to do. Idk why they're still teaching us that old stuff